in Emacs M-x shell running Elixir's IEx output Garbled code
When I run Elixir code(output string with non-ascii characters) by IEx under Emacs shell in win10 system, the output is Garbled, as shown below:
c:\Users\DLC\Desktop>iex test.exs
iex test.exs
Erlang/OTP 27 [erts-15.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

鐨勬柟寮弒dd
Interactive Elixir (1.17.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>

The contents of the file test.exs is:
IO.puts "的方式sdd"

How to deal with this problem?
I tried other language program which output non-ascii characters. The result is the same.

In Linux, I would say: check the LANG environment variable and the output of the locale program. I don't know how to do that on Windows though.
